# Не получается десериализовать xml

Tags: java, xml, simplexml, simpleframework

Нужно десериализовать xml [такого](http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp?date_req=23/07/2015) вида. Написал такой код, используя библиотеку [simple-xml](http://simple.sourceforge.net/home.php):

```
@Root
public class Valute {
    @Attribute
    public String ID;

    @Element
    public Integer NumCode;

    @Element
    public String CharCode;

    @Element
    public Integer Nominal;

    @Element
    public String Name;

    @Element
    public Double Value;
}

@Root
public class ValCurs {
    @Attribute
    public Date Date;

    @Attribute(name = "name", required = false)
    public String Name;

    @ElementList(inline = true, required = false)
    public List<Valute> Valutes;

    public Valute get(final String charCode) {
        for (Valute valute : Valutes) {
            if (valute.CharCode.equals(charCode))
                return valute;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static ValCurs parse(String xml) throws Exception {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
        RegistryMatcher m = new RegistryMatcher();
        m.bind(Date.class, new DateFormatTransformer(dateFormat));
        Reader reader = new StringReader(xml);
        Persister serializer = new Persister(m);
        return serializer.read(ValCurs.class, reader, false);
    }
}
```

Но при десериализации получаю в поле Valutes - null. Как это исправить?

Comment: а XStream не пробовали?

Comment: Не пробовал. А что с simple-xml никак не выйдет? Просто уже начал вроде...

Comment: я не могу сказать выйдет или нет, хотел еще порекомендовать посмотреть в сторону [Unmarshaller](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html)

Comment: Я не очень понял как ими пользоваться... Ну например в XStream передается объект для заполнения, но как указать какие его поля будут атрибутами, а какие нет, также вложенные списки как в моем примере не понятно как определять... Мне что в simple-xml понравилось - так это аннотации. Все через аннотации задается. Ну а с Unmarshaller вообще что-то очень странное. Ему не передается ни тип объекта, ни сам объект, тем не менее он возвращает какой-то не типизированный объект... Что в этом объекте? Как он определяет структуру xml?

Comment: Да кстати стоит добавить что если уж юзать какую-то другую библиотеку - мне надо чтобы она работала под андроидом! Т.к. приложение под андроид делаю.

Comment: XStream - построен очень похожим образом, и судя по отзыву некоторых - довольно быстр. Могу предположить, что в "simple-xml" по аналогии с JAXB нужно явно дописать конструктор по умолчанию для обоих классов. Причем для ValCurs, в нем надо явно проинициализировать `List`.